# value size does not match register size specified by the constraint and modifier

Tags: arm, clang, inline-assembly, arm64

In arm64, compiling the inline assembly below causes a warning below:

> value size does not match register size
>         specified by the constraint and modifier [-Wasm-operand-widths].

This is because the arm64's register is 64bit.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
asm volatile(
   "add %[a], %[a], %[b]  \n"
   :
   [a] "+r"(a)
   :
   [b] "r"(b)
   :
    );
```

> And clang give the fix advice, use constraint modifier "w".

Comment: *add the constraint "w"* - What exactly did you do here? `add.w`? Seems clear why second example would fail - you're mixing 64-bit register `x1` with 32-bit `int`s.

Comment: This program just is a simple demo that displays my program's warning.

Comment: Can you include the program when you add constraint `w`? You just have the error message for that case.

Comment: How about `"add %w[a], %w[a], %w[b]"`?

Comment: Your asm doesn't need to be `volatile`.  The output *is* a pure function of the inputs, so you want the compiler to optimize it accordingly.  Also, you forgot a clobber on `"x1"` in your 2nd version.

Comment: @Pe you are right.

Comment: In fact, this warning only occurs if the operand of the instruction is 32 bits and one is 64 bits in arm64. For example, ld/st instruction, the pointer is 64bit in arm64, but offset is %[n] is 32bit and the above situation.

Comment: @冯剑龙: then fix your question.  That's exactly what you'd expect: gcc/clang choose registers for their operand based on their type, but your question has a [mcve] which isn't really a MCVE: the types match so they should both choose `w` registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> value size does not match register size specified by the constraint and modifier

means:

your variable is `32bit` **not match** with ARM64's `64bit` register

you could:

- change your variable to `64bit`

```c
long a = 1;
long b = 2;
asm volatile(
   "add %[a], %[a], %[b]  \n"
   : [a] "+r"(a)
   : [b] "r"(b)
   :);
```

or

- use `32bit`=**W**ord register, by add prefix `w`

  - which is `clang` suggested

```c
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
asm volatile(
   "add %w[a], %w[a], %w[b]  \n"
   : [a] "+r"(a)
   : [b] "r"(b)
   :);
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to this warning is unmatched. In arm64, the register is 64bit width, but the int/float variables are 32bit. And if the type is double/int64_t or the variable is a pointer, it will don't cause a warning. So, you can try the way.

Answer (score 0):

As @David Wohlferd metioned in the commend, just use `%w[a]` replace `%[a]`.

That is, on ARM64 platform, you still would like to use 32-bit register, then insert a `w` between `%` and corresponding number that represents register.

Thus the whole program is modified to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arm_neon.h>

int main() {

    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    asm volatile(
        "add %w[a], %w[a], %w[b]  \n"
        :
        [a] "+r"(a)
        :
        [b] "r"(b)
        :
    );
    printf("after process, a=%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Btw, this [CSDN blog (in Chinese)](https://blog.csdn.net/Roland_Sun/article/details/42921131) is worth reading if you know nothing about arm inline assembler and get similar confusion like the author of this question.